# onEdit Script to auto run Filter on a tab

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to find a script that will run in a particular way, see below:

1. it runs on a specific tab in a spreadsheet
2. needs to either re-run a filter that i have in place on the tab
   OR
   can filter out blank Rows in a specific set of rows..i.e..from A13:G304
3. Needs to run when a specific Tab of the sheet is edited

---

Code

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 1;
  var tableRange = "A13:G304";

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy } );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jacob Jan Tuinstra
Thanks for that edit ..im fairly new to this so not sure how did you make the Script apear in the Code box ?

Comment: Check [this help page](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code).